# Keyword-based query returns undefined function for binding

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to use the keyeword-based queries in order to use lateral joins

I am basically copy-pasting this from the docs

```
AutoMessage
|> join(:inner, [am], a in assoc(am, :app))
```

But it will complain with

```
undefined function a/0
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

PS. Running on Ecto. 2.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the `Ecto.Query.join/3` macro is not imported into the scope, and the query is interpreted as regular elixir code by the compiler.

PS. The keyword-style query is the one using `from/2` macro, using other macros is the pipe-style or direct-style (not sure what terminology is used here).